# Why does it take 100 seconds to delete a blob?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I have code like this

```
BlobDownloadInfo blob = Client.GetBlockBlobClient(filePath).Download().Value;
...
Client.GetBlockBlobClient(filePath).DeleteIfExists();
```

And DeleteIfExists() reliably takes 00:01:42 (about 100 seconds) to delete my blob. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlobDownloadInfo` is an `IDisposable`. By not disposing it, we appear to be keeping open the connection and forcing `DeleteIfExists()` to wait for that connection to timeout. Updating the code to

```
using (BlobDownloadInfo blob = Client.GetBlockBlobClient(filePath).Download().Value)
```

causes `DeleteIfExists()` to return in about 00:00:00.15